# How to provide full path with Next.js Link component when using apps in sub-paths?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The project I am working on is a monorepo based off of Turbo and Next.js; multiple apps sharing the same common packages.

One of these packages is a called `ui`, containing common layouts and components. In the common layout, there is a toolbar with a user session menu, like this :

```
const AccountsMenu = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation("ui/main-layout");

  return (
    <div className="dropdown dropdown-end">
      <IconButton className="btn-ghost avatar">
        {avatarImage ? (
          <div className="w-10 rounded-full">
            <Image alt="User Avatar" src={DEFAULT_AVATAR} width="48" height="48" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <AccountCircleOutlineIcon size={40} />
        )}
      </IconButton>
      <ul
        tabIndex={0}
        className="menu menu-compact dropdown-content mt-3 p-2 shadow-lg drop-shadow-xl bg-neutral text-neutral-content rounded-box w-52"
      >
        <li>
          <a>
            <AccountIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
            {t("session.profile")}
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <CogIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
            {t("session.settings")}
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/accounts/auth/signout" legacyBehavior>
            <a>
              <LogoutIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
              {t("session.sign-out")}
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The "Sign out" menu item should link point to `/accounts/auth/signout`, but the `Link` component prefixes the `href` with the current app's subpath. For example, when viewing the layout from the `accounts` app, I get `/accounts/accounts/auth/signout` and when viewing from the `customer` app, I get `/customers/accounts/auth/signout`, etc.

Is there a way to tell the `Link` component which prefix to use, or is using a standard `Link` (which will force a page reload instead of using next/router) the only option, here?